# What are the definable subsets of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R},+)$. What are the subsets of that structure that are definable without parameters? I conjecture there are only four, namely $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\{0\}$, and $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. Is this correct?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know any easy ways to show that a set *isn't* definable?

Comment: @NoahSchweber No, I don't. I am a beginner in model theory.

Comment: Think about automorphisms. Suppose $D\subseteq\mathfrak{X}$ is definable and $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{X}$; what can you say about $\alpha[D]$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Let me guess, the image of that set is also definable?

Comment: Well, yes, but actually much more is true. Think about how automorphisms and formulas interplay: if $\mathfrak{X}\models\varphi(a)$ and $\alpha\in Aut(\mathfrak{X})$, what can you say about the truth value of $\varphi(\alpha(a))$ in $\mathfrak{X}$? What does that tell you about $D$ versus $\alpha[D]$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber That they satisfy the same formulas?

Comment: Yes, so if $D=\{a\in\mathfrak{X}: \mathfrak{X}\models\varphi(a)\}$, then $\alpha[D]=...$? (There's a snappy relationship between $D$ and $\alpha[D]$ I'm trying to get at.)

Comment: That they are the same set?

Comment: Exactly. So contrapositively, if you want to show that a set $E$ is *not* definable it's enough to exhibit a single automorphism moving some element of $E$ out of $E$ (or vice-versa). Now suppose $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is not one of the four sets in your OP; do you see how to construct such an automorphism? (More broadly, what's the "is automorphic to" relation in $(\mathbb{R}; +)$?)

Comment: Do you see how to finish the problem?

Comment: No, I don't. I am still a little stumped.

Comment: Alright, let's look at a specific example. Can you show that the set of positive reals isn't definable in this structure by exhibiting an automorphism swapping some positive real and some non-positive real?

Comment: Multiplication by -1.

Comment: Yup, that'll do it! *(Of course technically one should prove that $x\mapsto -x$ is in fact an automorphism, but that's easy: it's a bijection and $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)$.)* Now what about $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Multiplication by 1/2.

Comment: Yup. OK, now can you figure out what the "is automorphic to" relation is? That is, for which $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is there an automorphism sending $a$ to $b$?

Comment: I see. Either $a$ and $b$ are both 0, or neither of them are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning the comment thread above into an answer:

Most of the time it's easier to analyze the **orbit relation** of a structure than its definable sets per se. This is the relation $a\sim b$ iff there is an automorphism sending $a$ to $b$. Since automorphisms preserve $\models$, we know that every definable set is closed with respect to $\sim$ - or, more concretely, **every definable set is a union of $\sim$-classes**.

For example, in the case above we have $a\sim b$ iff both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero or both $a$ and $b$ are zero, so there are two $\sim$-classes ($\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$). Consequently there are only $2^2=4$ possible candidates for definable sets and it's easy to check that each of these four is in fact definable.

---

Now in general this won't always be enough to fully classify the definable subsets of a structure.. For example, the structure $(\mathbb{N};<)$ is **rigid** - it has no nontrivial automorphisms - but it can only have countably many (parameter-freely-)definable subsets. This is where more intricate techniques such as *quantifier elimination* come in. But for the specific problem above, looking at automorphisms is sufficient.